# How to add prebuilt .so files in android project 3.1.2

Tags: android

I am new to add the native libraries in android project.i was decompile the old APK file.i got the .so file from that decompiled source.now i am trying to that .so files in my project.but cannot add that file.i tried many times.it is showing "cannot resolve corresponding JNI function

Answer (score 0):

Create a JNI folder by clicking right side of mouse on app folder.

[image]

Then create properly images folder inside jniLibs and paste your .so files.

[image]

When you load .so file you can do it like this without libs. That's it.

```
        System.loadLibrary("c++_shared");
        System.loadLibrary("logs");
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.when i create the jni folder its creating the cpp and jni folder.where i can put that .so files

Comment: it is showing the error Cannot resolve corresponding JNI function Java_vehtec_soft_hellojnitest_MainActivity_Initialize

Comment: don't pay attention that error, if you declare your native method like this, it is working 100% ```private static native void manager_ui_init(String logPath, String uiDbPath, String netmanagerDbPath);```

Comment: will you please share any sample

Answer (score 0):

The default directory to add native libraries is src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a

To support more CPU/eabi variants have a look at this [link](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis).